# Docker-Compose Elkstack

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, kibana

I'd like to get an Elkstack running on my virtual machine. I read up on the topic already a while ago but just recently figured out how to use docker-compose. I found a complete compose file on github (https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) which is capable of composing the whole stack, however I ran into two questions: Kibana is awaiting input from Elasticsearch on the url "http://elasticsearch:9200" - The url is obviously not resolving to anything - Hows that supposed to work? I made changes to it so it tries to connect to localhost:9200 but Elasticsearch is refusing the connection - I checked the running containers and saw that elasticsearch is indeed running but using "lsof -i :9200" (or 9300) did not show anything which means it is not listening on the port right? Or would it now show up due to the fact that it is running in docker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ` Kibana is awaiting input from Elasticsearch on the url "http://elasticsearch:9200" ` where do you see that? For me everything seems to start up normally. Just performed `git clone` and docker-compose up -d`

Comment: give your output of `docker ps` and if there are containers not started or stopped you need to perform `docker logs container-id` to show the logs. But I don't see any issue in this git. I can access everything with http://ip-of-my-vm:port

Comment: Ah alright, thanks a lot! I saw that elasticsearch quit on me and using the log command was able to figure out why. I gave my VM not enough RAM - now it is running correctly. A follow up question: When I was running those containers separately I had to expose the ports in the dockerfile and then specify which ports I'd like to open to the outworld when running the command using the -p flag - Hows that handled in a docker-compose scenario? Do I just need to specify the ports in the composing files and I can then send logs from an external server to my stack? Thanks a ton!

Comment: If you build your own images, you need to expose ports in the dockerfile. This are ports which will be exposed on your container. So other containers in the same environment (server) can access the container from that port. From the outside you can not access such a container. Because the port is only open on the container. Not on the serverside. So herefor we use `-p port_host:port_container` to map a container port on a server port. So if you want to access your container form the outside using docker compose: you'll need to map the exposed ports (of your dockerfile) on a server-port.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/version-2 here you can see how it works. So in the example port 5000 will be exposed in the dockerfile (you can not see the dockerfile, but you can assume it). So the container port 5000 is open. Now in docker-compose.yml you can see "5000:5000". Which means you map port 5000 of your container on port 5000 of your server. If you don't add this part to your docker-compose your port will only be open on the container-side (thanks to the expose). It will be not open on the server side so not accessible from the outside.

Comment: So to bring this example back to your case. The original dockerfile of kibana will expose port 5601. As you can see here: https://github.com/docker-library/kibana/blob/144fccdd6a2c8c05fc79c27d3eb62a90b274f19b/5/Dockerfile. The docker-compose file is using kibana:5 image (so which is exposing 5601). The docker-compose.yml https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml is mapping the exposed port of kibana on your server port 5601.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thank you very much. However, using docker inspect on the created logstash container I fail to find any exposed ports (even though it is indeed running correctly now). I'd like to change the port from 5000 to a different one and I planned on doing that using the Dockerfile in logstash folder but now I am unsure whether this is the right way since inspect does not list any currently exposed ports (which it should imo)

Comment: I don't see why you want to change the port on the container-side. But you can change the docker-compose.yml and map 5000 of your container on 5001 of your server/vm (as an example). This can be useful when there are only a few ports open on your server/vm. But on containerside you can expose every port so I don't see why you want to change that. With this command you can check the exposed port + check on what it's mapped: `docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' container-id`

Comment: Hope you get it. Your external server (which will connect with the stack) will only need to know the port of the server (on which you map). So if you change your port inside the dockerfile. It hasn't impact at all on your external server. It's only important for that server on which port you map. So if you have `-p 8080:80` than your external server only needs to know 8080. It does not matter for that server if your container is exposing 80 or some other port. Just the mapped port is important.

Comment: Oh wow now I get it completely. I don't know why I was thinking about changing the container port, that makes no sense indeed. Thank you very much for your very detailed help! :)

Comment: Ok, I need to ask something again: How do I go about adding Dashboards  into the Kibana container? I tried to add them using the Dockerfile but the normal procedure needs curl - Is there a better practice than that? Thanks again! :)

Comment: I don't know much about that. Can't you upload dashboards in the kibana webconsole? I'm sorry. Don't know much more about Kibana.

Comment: That sounds like a better idea! Thank you very much again :)